Expected value/distribution of a random walk that can't repeat rows or columns on a grid where each cell has a real number value?
Given that you have a matrix $A \in R^{n \times n}$, we define a random walk, $X$, of length $1 \leq k \leq n$ on $A$ as a walk where no two cells share the same row or column. An example of such a walk on $A \in R^{5 \times 5}$ might be $X = (a_{1, 1}, a_{2, 2}, a_{3, 4})$. We define the value of $X$ as the sum of the values of the cells it contains. In our example, the value of $X$ would be $Y = a_{1, 1} + a_{2, 2} + a_{3, 4}$. How would I approach finding the expected value and/or distribution of $Y$?

Calling this a "walk" makes me, at least, think that there should be some special connection between the cell location of the $i$-th cell and the $(i+1)$-th cell, but the way you ask the question makes me believe that there is no such special connection, and what you are generating is more like a random sample. Am I incorrect?

Yes, the only connection between steps is that they don't intersect. There is no special connection. I actually found the solution to this problem recently. The expected value should just be E(X | k) = kE(a), where E(a) is just the average of all the elements of A. We can also find P(k) by just counting the samples of length k and dividing by the total number of samples where rows and columns don't intersect.
